# Adding nearest parking address to a Google Business listing

Tags: google-business

How do I add the nearest location of parking to my Google Business listing?

Answer (score 2):

While there is no explicit field to mark information like parking in the Google My Business dashboard, you can use Attributes to denote this info and much more.

Rather than rewrite an already fine resource, I'll just share the source material:

https://www.chatmeter.com/blog/how-to-improve-your-local-seo-ranking-right-now-with-google-attributes

Google's own documentation is here:

https://support.google.com/business/answer/3370250?hl=en#attributes